# Windows 7 not booting after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, boot, windows-7, xubuntu, data-recovery

I have Samsung sf511 with Windows 7 Home preinstalled.

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 last night. First I downloaded ubuntu 12.10 DVD iso and burned a DVD. I rebooted and changed the boot option to DVD and let the Ubuntu DVD run. I selected "Install ubuntu alongside windows 7". In the next step I allocated the diskspace . Ubuntu installed perfectly and it ran OK.

I spent a good time exploring Ubuntu. When I restarted to start my work on Windows again and selected Windows 7 to boot, it showed blue screen after booting up (after logging in). I tried restarting several times but the same blue screen keep showing  at the same point of bootup. I also restored windows to an earlier time.

Left with no option I booted from Samsung provided windows recovery option. The recovery process ran fine but when it restarted to boot Windows for the first time all I see is a black screen. Nothing happens. It switches between dark command promt screen to a pitch black screen as if it's rebooting after every 10 seconds or so.

The laptop can be booted from the DVD Drive or USB drive but is not booting from Harddisk.

What should I do in order to use both Windows 7 and Ubuntu?

Comment: Please run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and indicate the URL it will display.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 EFI on my Acer (and I found it to be the only way it would work, for me):

Firstly, defragment and run `chkdsk` in Windows, then use Windows to shrink its  `C: drive`

Then use `Parted Magic Live Disk` to prepare Linux partitions in Free Space created.

Windows has 3 partitions:

```
/efi      boot
/system   restore
/windows  c drive
```

You'll need to create the following with GParted:

Create an extended partition then your logical drives.

I use the ext4 filesystem.

```
/boot    256 Megs 
/root    8 gigs (min) I use more 12 gigs
/swap    2 gigs is fine
/home    remaining size available on your HDD
```

When you install Ubuntu you'll be asked where to install select same order as above and it select `hdd as boot`, it should at end of install see Windows as other OS and install Grub accordingly.

Trust this info assists.